# Inverting a function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: analysis

I have to show this function is bijective. from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2 $

$f(x,y)=((x^2+1)y,x^3)$

My first instinct is to try to invert it but I'm not sure how to invert an $\mathbb{R}^2 $ function.

To rigorously show this function is bijective do I need to show it's both injective and surjective or can I just find the inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "just" find the inverse, by solving $f(x,y)=(a,b)$.

You find $x^3=b$ then $x=b^{1/3}$ and $(x^2+1)y=a$ then $y=\frac{a}{1+b^{2/3}}$

Then $g: (a,b) \mapsto (b^{1/3}, \frac{a}{1+b^{2/3}})$ is the inverse and you have $f(g(a,b)) = (a,b)$ and $g(f(x,y))=(x,y)$ which proves that $f$ is bijective.

Note that finding the inverse naturally proves that $f$ is injective and surjective.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to explicitly find the inverse, then here's proof of injectivity:

If $f(x', y') = f(x, y)$, then $x'^3 = x^3$ which implies $x' = x$, and then $(x'^2 + 1)y' = (x^2 + 1)y' = (x^2 + 1)y$ which implies $y' = y$, hence it is injective.

And for surjectivity, you essentially use the inverse values found by fonfonx, but without showing that they define unique values of $x$ and $y$ you at least know that any $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is in the image of $f$.